# SAS Python integration

Tags: python, python-2.7, sas, rhel

I'm testing the python integration in sas,I clone the github project [https://github.com/sassoftware/enlighten-integration](https://github.com/sassoftware/enlighten-integration/tree/master/SAS_Base_OpenSrcIntegration).I compiled [the java class](https://github.com/sassoftware/enlighten-integration/tree/master/SAS_Base_OpenSrcIntegration/src/dev) with java 7 then I tried to execute a python script in this way:

```
*** WORKING DIRECTORY      (----- USER UPDATE NEEDED -----);
%let WORK_DIR = /tmp;   
*** SYSTEM PYTHON LOCATION (----- USER UPDATE NEEDED -----); 
%let PYTHON_EXEC_COMMAND = /usr/bin/python2.6;      

*** JAVA LIBRARIES/CLASS FILES LOCATION;
%let JAVA_BIN_DIR = /tmp/SAS.jar;
%put &JAVA_BIN_DIR;
OPTIONS SET=CLASSPATH "&JAVA_BIN_DIR."; 

options linesize = MAX; 
ods html close; 
ods listing; 


*** VALIDATE JAVA CLASSPATH; 
data _null_; 
  length _x1 $32767; 
  _x1 = strip(sysget("CLASSPATH"));  
  _x2 = index(upcase(trim(_x1)), %upcase("&JAVA_BIN_DIR")); 
  if _x2 = 0 then put "ERROR: Invalid Java Classpath.";
run; 


/*** Part I: Python ***/
data _null_;
  length rtn_val 8;
  *** Python program takes working directory as first argument;
  python_pgm = "&WORK_DIR./convert_ch.py";
  python_arg1 = "&WORK_DIR";      
  python_call = cat('"', trim(python_pgm), '" "', trim(python_arg1), '"'); 

  declare javaobj j("dev.SASJavaExec", "&PYTHON_EXEC_COMMAND", python_call); 
  j.callIntMethod("executeProcess", rtn_val);
run;
```

It works perfectly but if I try to change the python version:

```
%let PYTHON_EXEC_COMMAND = /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/python27;
```

It doesn't work:

```
mag 13, 2016 10:48:35 AM dev.SASJavaExec executeProcess
Informazioni: Executing [/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/python27, /data/shareddata/projects/smartdata/flat_file/tmp/convert_ch.py, /data/shareddata/projects/smartdata/flat_file/tmp] ...
mag 13, 2016 10:48:35 AM dev.SASJavaExec executeProcess
Informazioni: Starting external process ...
mag 13, 2016 10:48:35 AM dev.SASJavaExec executeProcess
Grave: Failed to start external Process: 
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
     at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
     at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
     at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
     at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
     at dev.SASJavaExec.executeProcess(SASJavaExec.java:151)
```

I'm using RHEL 6.6(Santiago). By default the Python's version is 2.6 and I install the 2.7 in this way:

```
sudo sh -c 'wget -qO- http://people.redhat.com/bkabrda/scl_python27.repo >> /etc/yum.repos.d/scl.repo'
yum install python27
```

maybe I made a mistake during the installation of python 2.7?

Comment: What if you install python 2.7 in /usr/bin?  Maybe SAS has hardcoded some pathnames that it shouldn't have.

Comment: i don't think so, look dock block in java source code /**
     * Constructs a SASJavaExec object with NO command line arguments to STDIN.
     *
     * param execCommand Path to executable, i.e. C:\Anaconda\python.exe
     * param script      Path to Class or script to execute, including any command line arguments,
     *                    i.e. C:\Path\to\digitsdata_svm.py
     */